# Why is my tensorflow model transforming binary classification labels from 0 and 1 to .7?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I have been working on a tensorflow model that predicts short term positive and negative trends in the stock market using momentum indicators. I have the model set up to take in a 32x7 matrix of the 7 indicators at each of the last 32 time steps. If the price increases after the last time step the label is 1 and if it stays the same or decreases it is a 0.

I have a custom metric function that prints out the prediction and the true value for each epoch and what I have found is that the true values are not 0 or 1 they hover at ~.7. For binary classification this is not helpful because all the predictions will also hover at ~.7. Can anyone explain to me what may be causing the model to alter the labels in this way?

Here is the model and a screenshot of the first 10 epochs for reference.

```
def true(y_true, y_pred):
  return y_true
def pred(y_true, y_pred):
  return y_pred

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', 
            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
          tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2,2)),
          tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, kernel_size=(2,2), padding='same', 
            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
          tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2,2)),
          tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
  ])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5,), loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), metrics= 
     ['binary_accuracy', 'mae', pred, true])
model.fit(X,Y, validation_data = (X_val, Y_val), epochs=100, batch_size=100, callbacks=[])
```

[First 10 epochs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGJ6.png)

Comment: You are looking at the mean of the true values, not at the actual true values themselves. The true values are not changed by keras.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that makes sense, but why do the predictions all stay at that mean? I am trying to create a deployable model but it needs to be able to predict 0 and 1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used `sigmoid` activation function in the final layer of your binary classification model, which is absolutely correct.

`Sigmoid` activation function will give output results between 0 to 1.

> For small values (<=0.5), 
> where sigmoid returns a value close to zero, the
> predicted class will be assumed 0. 
> For large values (>0.5),
>  the result of
> when the function gets close to 1, then the predicted class will be assumed 1.

You can use the below code to change the output values from decimal to 0,1

```
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)
print('Predictions:\n', predictions.numpy())
```